# Ubuntu,Ubuntu (no effects),Gnome,Gnome Classic

Tags: 11.10

These are the various options of ubuntu that I am asked to chose from.How do these differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Ubuntu** uses Unity with Compiz.
- **Ubuntu (no effects)** uses Unity 2D with Metacity.
- **Gnome** is, I think, Gnome Shell with Mutter as the compositor.
- **Gnome Classic** is the similar to the old Classic traditional Ubuntu desktop, using panels. It's not the same because it had to be rebuilt using GTK3 widgets.

The "no effects" and "Gnome Classic" variants are the ones you'll want on desktops with little or no graphical acceleration. Compiz and Mutter both require a certain amount of hardware heft to run.